# What do we (really) mean when we say that two random variables are equivalent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If we define random variables as a measurable function from measurable set $(S,\mathbb{S})$ to measurable set $(T, \mathbb{T})$, where $\mathbb{S}, \mathbb{T}$ are $\sigma$-algebra on S and T. Some texts claim that two random variables X and Y are equivalent if P(X=Y) = 1. However any particular element $\{t\}, \forall t \in T$ may not be measurable, as there is no guarantee that $\{t\} \in \mathbb{T}$, then what do we mean by P(X=Y)? because apparently $\sum_{t \in T} P(X=t, Y=t)$ is not always well defined

I guess an example could be: $S = T = \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{S} = \mathbb{T} = \sigma\{\{\mbox{even numbers}\}, \{\mbox{odd numbers}\}\}$, $X = 2 * s$, $Y = s + 4$. It is my understanding that both $X, Y$ are measurable functions because their inverse image of any measurable set in $(T, \mathbb{T})$ is a measurable set in $(S, \mathbb{S})$. That makes them valid random variables. But $\{X=Y\}$ is not measurable

Comment: A random variable $X$ is a mapping from $(S, \mathbb S)$ to $(T, \sigma(X))$ where $\sigma(X)$ is a sub-algebra of $\mathbb T$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: No, $\sigma(X)$ is by definition the sigma-algebra generated by the sets $X^{-1}(B)$, $B\in\mathbb{T}$, and hence if $X:S\to T$, then $\sigma(X)$ 'lives' on $S$.

Answer (score 2):

There's a major misconception here. First, what do we really mean by $P(X=Y)=1$? Well, we mean exactly what it says: We mean that $P(E)=1$, where $E$ is the event $$E=\{s\in S\,:\,X(s)=Y(s)\}.$$

I imagine you can concoct an example where that set $E$ is not measurable. (EDIT: For example, let $S=T=\{0,1\}$, and give both $S$ and $T$ the trivial sigma-algebra. Then *any* function from $S$ to $T$ is measurable. If $X=1$ and $Y=\Bbb 1_{\{0\}}$ then the set where $X=Y$ is not measurable. Thanks to Did.) But it's measurable in the situations that actually arise in practice (as far as I know - if there's a counterexample that actually comes up I'd love to hear about it).

The major misconception is that this has something to do with $\sum_{t\in T}P(X=t,Y=t)$. That is not the same as $P(X=Y)$ even in very nice situations. For example, take $S=[0,1]$, with the Borel sigma-algebra and Lebesgue measure, and say $T$ is also $[0,1]$ with the Borel sigma-algebra. Let $X(s)=Y(s)=s$ for all $s\in S$. Then the event $X=Y$ is certainly measurable, and $P(X=Y)=1$. But $\sum_{t\in T}P(X=t,Y=t)=0$.

Measures are countably additive, not arbitrarily additive.

Comment: @Did The functions in that example are real-valued. Of course there is no such example in that context. The question was about random variables taking values in an arbitrary measurable space.

Comment: Except in that example $Y$ is not measurable, hence $Y$ is not a "random variable". It seems clear to me that there should exist examples where $X$ and $Y$ are measurable but $E$ is not, but it can't be that trivial...???

Comment: Why $Y$ in my previous example is not measurable? If $\mathbb S=2^S$, ever function on $(S,\mathbb S)$ is measurable.

Comment: A sufficient condition for E to be measurable is that the diagonal should be a measurable subset of $T^2$ (with its product $\sigma$-algebra). In practice, ordinary probability theory normally only considers problems in which T is standard Borel, in which case this does hold.

Comment: @Did It would be easier to answer that question if you hadn't deleted the example...

Comment: At your service:: "OK, then phony examples are easy to concoct: $T=\{0,1\}$, $\mathbb T=\{\varnothing,T\}$, $\mathbb S\ne2^S$, $X=1$, $Y=\mathbf 1_A$ with $A\notin\mathbb S$."

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes of course; hence my assertion that this doesn't go wrong in practice. The first question is what's an example where the diagonal is not measurable...

Comment: @Did Hmm. I was actually thinking of the standard test regarding measurability of the set where $S>\lambda$. Which is of course irrelevant here - sorry.

Comment: Indeed. I just thought I would point out more specifically *why* this doesn't go wrong in practice (of course you know it already, but a novice reader may not).

Comment: Gotta go, guys - if you get this sorted out while I'm in class please don't delete that comment. heh...

Comment: @Did Otoh I don't see why your $Y$ _is_ measurable, given what you said. But it's easy to make $Y$ measurable if we're a little more specific. See edit. Thanks...

Comment: The example in your answer is a special case of the one in my comment.

Comment: @Did As I realized a little later. I had this and that switched... never mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think, though, it shouldn't be too hard to construct sets for which E is not measurable. I added an example in the original question

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry I did not get why E is not measurable would not be a problem in practice. A state of partial information, such as in a stochastic process, may require definition of $\sigma$-algebras that is smaller than the power set (for countable) or Borel (for uncountable). Then does this mean we cannot talk about {X=Y} unless we are under the "common" $\sigma$-algebra definitions?